# LoadLibrary() - order of search

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, mapi, loadlibrary

So I have code like this

```
m_hInstMail = ::LoadLibraryA("MAPI32.DLL"); 

ASSERT(m_hInstMail != (HINSTANCE) NULL);

//  Now get the pointer to the send function
(FARPROC&) m_lpfnSendMail = GetProcAddress(m_hInstMail, "MAPISendMail");
CWnd* pParentWnd = CWnd::GetSafeOwner(NULL, &hWndTop);
int nError = m_lpfnSendMail((ULONG)0, (ULONG)(pParentWnd->GetSafeHwnd()), &m_message, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG | flags, (ULONG)0);
```

The system file  "MAPI32.DLL" is present in both System32 and SysWOW64 folder.
And both of these files have different sizes despite have same name.

How can I know which one is being called by LoadLibraryA()?

**Background about the real problem** -- When I compile this code for 32 bit system it works fine but for 64 bit system I get a server busy message when the message is being sent using MAPISendMail() around 5 seconds after Outlook pops up with the composed message.

[image]

EDIT:
1) The problem is kind of similar to what this user mentions

[Link to MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d4d1409d-8520-447d-9105-2b0e72575922/mapisendmail-mail-window-is-under-application?forum=outlookdev)

2) I have used the unicode versio of the call MapiSendMailW() and still the problem persists.

3) Expanded the code to include syntax of how MapiSendMail is being called.

Comment: `System32` is the native 64-bit system folder. `SysWOW64` is the 32-bit emulated system folder used when you run 32-bit applications (in the 32-bit emulated environment) on a 64-bit system.  Have a read of: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Richard Yes I am aware of that

Comment: *How can I know which one is being called by LoadLibraryA()?* -- Use [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the name of the module loaded.

Comment: The loader searches in `"%SystemRoot%\\System32"`. Under WOW64 emulation, this path gets automatically redirected to `"%SystemRoot%\\SysWOW64"`. I don't have experience with MAPI, but perhaps [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296721) are relevant to your situation, which suggest using `MAPISendMailW` on Windows 8+.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend that you abandon ANSI. Windows is natively UTF-16.  Using codepages is a legacy from the days of Windows 9x, and most new functions added to the Windows API since Vista are only available for Unicode.

Comment: The code is incomplete. We don't know, what the function signature looks like, for example. Who knows, you may have gotten the signature wrong, and that just happens to fail on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @physicist _"...How can I know which one is being called by LoadLibraryA()?"_ then you already know the answer - so what's the point of the question?

Comment: this window nothing common with `LoadLibrary` . this happens when *STA* com apartment make remote call (to another process) and wait on reply (inside inner com message loop) when it got some not trivial windows messages - it show this dialog. question why server not reply

Comment: If the library loaded, you got the right one. You won't be able to load a DLL as an executable unless the bitness matches your calling process. Loading a DLL as a resource is a different case...but you're loading it to execute a call. Why can't you just leave off the LoadLibrary mumbo jumbo and just link to mapi32.lib or whatever it is? And call the normal way? What is so special you need to jump through those hoops?

Comment: What flags did you use to call MAPISendMail?

Comment: @xMRi I have updated the code and shown how MAPISendMail is being used

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hanks, let me try that